# Why is this regex expression not mathing JUST the email?

Tags: regex

http://regexr.com/3a8dc

I am trying to parse a vCard file for a small personal utility I need for my job. in this example I am trying to match just the email address. The line in the file looks like this:

```
EMAIL;PREF;INTERNET:MikeSmith@FastFoodInc.com
```

My Regex looks like this:

```
(?:^EMAIL;PREF;INTERNET:)(\w+@\w+\.\w+)\n
```

If I'm not mistaken, I have a non-matching group, and a matching group.

```
(?:^EMAIL;PREF;INTERNET:)
```

Should this not be to match but not capture the group that begins with "`(?:^EMAIL;PREF;INTERNET:)`" and then the second group should be captured? I am capturing the entire line.

Comment: You need to understand what is exactly a capture.

Comment: I'd also advise against not using that as a regex to find the email address. Would be easier/safer to split on the `:` and take the right hand side by the look of things

Comment: Change `?:` to `?<=` and see the magic!

Answer (score 1):

You're using match and capture backwards. Matched refers to the entirety of the text that the pattern matches, and captured refers to the part in the parens. So you're not trying to *match* just the email, you're trying to *capture* just the email. Your pattern matches the whole line, which is what regexr.com is showing you. If you then inspect the captured portion, you'll see it contains what you expect.

Also, there's no need to group the first section if you're not going to capture it, so you can use:

```
^EMAIL;PREF;INTERNET:(\w+@\w+\.\w+)\n
```

And if you know that only an email address ever follows that label, can you probably further shorten to:

```
^EMAIL;PREF;INTERNET:(.+)$
```

Comment: Note that the anchors `^` and `$` don't always mean *start of the line* and *end of the line* depending of the regex engine and the used mode. Note too that in the second pattern `$` is not needed.